# How to fix 'Cannot read property "1.0" from null' jQuery problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rhino

I use rhino 1.7R2 to run JavaScript code outside of a browser to test it. This works fine but as soon as the tested code uses jQuery I get this error message:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "1.0" from null (jquery.js#6313)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3557)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3535)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3563)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3582)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3595)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectElem(ScriptRuntime.java:1343)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c30._c1(jquery.js:6313)
```

At line 6313 of jquery.js I don't see code which could cause such an error message:

```
6313   jQuery.extend({
```

Anyone knows on what object jquery tries to access a property named "1.0"? I probably need to mock this object but up to now I was not able to find out what jquery tries to do here.

Comment: Care to give us code that bugs it out?

Comment: Does Rhino have a DOM API and `window` object? I'd imagine jQuery wouldn't run too flash without them.

Comment: DOM API and window object is present (Already mocked it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I mocked only "location" but not "window.location" (Or the other way around, can't remember).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have jquery file included.

Comment: The errors are referencing a file named `jquery.js`. I sure hope that file has jQuery in it :)

Comment: jQuery is included. Otherwise the error message wouldd be "jQuery not found" or something like that.